# Internal Server Error when trying to log in with Facebook to Django server

Tags: django, facebook, django-rest-framework, django-allauth, django-rest-auth

I have a Django REST server which I updated recently from using Python 2.7 to 3.4. The server uses Django REST framework on top of Django, with django-allauth and django-rest-auth for Facebook login support.

Now, after the update, I cannot login to the server with Facebook anymore. When I send a POST to the server, I get the following error:

```
Internal Server Error: /rest-auth/facebook/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 132, in get_response response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 58, in wrapped_view return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 71, in view return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 452, in dispatch response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 449, in dispatch response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\rest_auth\views.py", line 51, in post if not self.serializer.is_valid():
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 187, in is_valid self._validated_data = self.run_validation(self.initial_data)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 370, in run_validation value = self.validate(value)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\rest_auth\registration\serializers.py", line 31, in validate token.account = login.account
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py", line 668, in __set__ (value, self.field.rel.to._meta.object_name)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 496, in __repr__ u = six.text_type(self)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\allauth\socialaccount\models.py", line 104, in __str__ return force_text(self.user)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py", line 608, in __get__ "%s has no %s." % (self.field.model.__name__, self.field.name)
django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedObjectDoesNotExist: SocialAccount has no user.
[13/Apr/2015 08:53:30]"POST /rest-auth/facebook/ HTTP/1.1" 500 115908
```

What could be causing this? I have done no changes to the code after updating Python and the libraries, and it worked before the update. I deleted the old database and created a new one via syncdb but it didn't help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`RelatedObject` has been removed in Django 1.8 in favour of `ForeignObjectRel`. [Source](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/21414)

The allauth version you are using does not support Django 1.8.

Comment: Any workaround for this ? I am using django 1.9 with django-allauth (0.25.2). And I am getting the same error.